# Vertical-top align ul items side by side

Tags: css, html, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I set my UL items to have `display: inline-block`, 30% width, and they align side by side corretly.

But, they vertical align to bottom if there is a bigger li.

Is there any way to top align this items?

One solution that I don't like is to have a Javascript that equals height from all elements, but don't seens to be a clean solution to this problem, since different rows may need different heights.

Code snippet here..

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>Item A with Long text</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quisquam debitis officia impedit sed omnis dolorem nihil doloribus dolore provident totam unde minus possimus quae dignissimos quo necessitatibus ipsa molestias.
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Item B with Short Text</h1>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Item C with Short Text</h1>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Item D with Short Text</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `vertical-align:top;` to the li?

Comment: Of couse that I tried j08691.
As scdr explained, this is a white space bug.

Comment: "Of course"? Why would anyone assume that you tried this when you didn't mention it, nor is it in your code. Not to mention that sdcr uses it in his answer and without it it doesn't work. Your question has as much to do with vertical alignment as it does with white space.

Comment: j08691, you comment do NOT solve my problem. That's the point. Useless comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also related to the famous [white space](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) bug.

See this demo with the fix using font size https://jsfiddle.net/8hfgmwLy/2/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h1>Item A with Long text</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quisquam debitis officia impedit sed omnis dolorem nihil doloribus dolore provident totam unde minus possimus quae dignissimos quo necessitatibus ipsa molestias.
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Item B with Short Text</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Item C with Short Text</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Item D with Short Text</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    background: grey;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```